# PUT multiple related records in Data API request

Tags: filemaker

In the [documentation](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/restapi/#work-with-records_create-record) from FMI the HTTP-body example for creating records using FMS16 Data API (REST) looks like this

```
{"data": 
    {
    "field_1": "value_1",
    "field_2": "value_2",
    "repetitionField(1)" : "fieldValue",
    "Orders::OrderDate.0":"12/22/2015"
    }
}
```

The last attribute `Orders::OrderDate.0` sets a value to a field on a related record and since the record don´t already exist it will be created.

My question focus on the `.0` suffix of the attribute name. It looks to me like the `0` indicates a serial/identifier for on which related record the value should be inserted. This leads me to wonder if it is possible to create more then one related record in the same request that creates the parent record.

The below body returns error that the record does not exist, but why can one related record be created but not two?

```
{"data": 
    {
    "field_1": "value_1",
    "field_2": "value_2",
    "repetitionField(1)" : "fieldValue",
    "Orders::OrderDate.0":"12/22/2015",
    "Orders::OrderDate.1":"11/11/2011"
    }
}
```

Any clue if the above code should work? Am I missing something?

I am fully aware that I can (should) post several requests aimed at the related tables layout to create the related records. I just wish to know, since the `.0` notation is in the documentation, does it should have a valid function?

Comment: I think you could have a better chance of an answer on this from the FileMaker community where also staff from FileMaker appear from time to time. https://community.filemaker.com/community/discussions/

Comment: Thanks,but it took them a long while to just approve my request to get an account. Grew tired of waiting... =)

Comment: Found this under the notes section in the doc you linked to: "Only one related record can be created per create record call." So there you have it. Looks llike it behaves similarly to record creation from a portal, where you also can only create one related record at a time.

Comment: You should write it as a answer and get some cred...
Feel stupid for missing that info

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this under the notes section in the doc you linked to:

> "Only one related record can be created per create record call."

So there you have it. Looks like it behaves similarly to record creation from a portal, where you also can only create one related record at a time.